# Idiomatic way of keeping a stateful lookup table with indexes in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, hashmap, state

I am fairly new to Clojure and functional programming in general and I've been struggling with the following problem. I'd like to assign a unique and stable index to a series of tokens (strings). Since there will be a lot more lookups than insertions, a hash-map seemed to be the way to go.

In Java I would've written something along the lines of

```
int last = 0; 
HashMap<String, Integer> lut = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

function Integer getIndex(String token) {
   Integer index = lut.get(token); 
   if(index == null) 
      last++;
      lut.put(token, last);
      return last;
    else { 
      return index;
    }
}
```

The transliterated version in Clojure would be something like

```
(def last-index (atom 0))
(def lookup-table (atom {}))

(defn get-index [token]
  (if (nil? (get @lookup-table token))
    (do 
      (swap! last-index inc)
      (swap! lookup-table assoc token @last-index)
      @last-index)
    (get @lookup-table token)))
```

But this doesn't seem to be very idomatic since it basically side-effects and doesn´t even hide it.

So how would you do this without having the two atoms for keeping state?

Comment: It's worth noting that you never want to have code like this that modifies two atoms that depend on each other. Atoms are for independent state. If you need to mutate multiple that depend on one another, you should use refs and dosync. Isn't particularly relevant here, given Ankur's answer, but something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer given by Ankur is not thread safe, although I don't think seh's description of why is very helpful, and his alternatives are worse. It's reasonable to say "Well I'm not worried about multiple threads now", in which case that answer is fine. But it's valuable to be able to write such things safely even if you don't need that guarantee in any particular instance, and the only safe way is to do all your logic inside the `swap!`, like so:

```
(let [m (atom {})]
  (defn get-index [token]
    (get (swap! m
                #(assoc % token (or (% token) (count %))))
         token)))
```

You can speed this up a bit by avoiding a `swap!` if there is already an entry when the function is called, and by avoiding an assoc if there is already an entry once you've entered the `swap!`, but you *must* "double check" that the map doesn't have an entry for the current token before just assigning it `(count %)`, because some other thread may have snuck in before you started `swap!`ing (but after you decided to `swap!`), and assigned a value for the current token, in which case you must respect that assignment instead of making a new one.

Edit: as an aside, the Java version of course has the same thread-safety problem, because by default everything in Java is mutable and not thread-safe. At least in Clojure you have to put a `!` in there, saying "Yes, I know this is dangerous, I know what I'm doing."

So in some sense Ankur's solution is a *perfect* translation of the Java code, but even better would be to improve it!

Comment: I'm curious as to what about my note you thought would make matters worse. I was brief, but my point was that it's not safe to unconditionally rebind the atom here, because two racing threads doing so will drop changes that the other tried to make. How you coordinate those two racing threads is a matter of design. Rereading the documentation for `swap!` today, I see that it spins internally until it sets a value consistently, and hence my suggestion for using `compare-and-set!` would be overkill. I still think that using `dosync` against a *ref* is the most clear way to go.

Comment: Two threads racing to `(swap! a f)` never "throw away" changes. The atom will always be in a consistent state, and eventually `a` will be set to `(f (f old-a))`. The problem is that he's building `f1` and `f2` based on information from *outside* of `swap!` that may be out of date. `compare-and-swap!` just makes it *easier* to make this mistake, IMO. `dosync` is fine, as long as you make sure it's a ref rather than an atom, but it's usually overkill for managing a single reference, and knowing how to write a good `swap!` is important.

Answer (score 0):

Single map in atom will be enough:

```
(def m (atom {}))
;adding new string to map
(swap! m #(assoc %1 "Hello" (count %)))
;get an index
(@m "Hello")

(defn get-index [token] 
    (or (@m token) 
        ((swap! m #(assoc %1 token (count %))) token)))
```

You basically tried to map the Java imperative code to clojure and thats why you got that solution in your question. Try to think in terms of composing expressions rather than thinking step wise imperative style.

Comment: Why did you propose use of `swap!` rather than `compare-and-set!`, or even rebinding the map within a `dosync` call? If you're expecting to be racing against other threads, using `swap!` here allows overwriting their changes with yours unknowingly.